# convert string Jan 1, 2000 12:00 AM to date-time in r

Tags: r

Real simple question that I can't quite find the right answer to.

How would I convert a string of  convert string Jan 1, 2000 12:01 AM to date-time in r?

Comment: Read `?as.POSIXct`, and `?strptime` for discussion of the `%`-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hidden in `?strptime` -

```
x <- "Jan 1, 2000 12:01 AM"
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC"
```

Or use `lubridate` -

```
lubridate::mdy_hm(x)
#[1] "2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Didn't realize that lubridate command existed.

Comment: Appreciate it! Looks like I was using the wrong time format there.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
 parse_date(x)
[1] "2000-01-01 00:01:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
x <- "Jan 1, 2000 12:01 AM"
```